# NULLIF produces incorrect output in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, nullif

This following code should produce the same values for columns `lag` and `lag2`:

```
CREATE TABLE bug1 (
  id INT,
  value INT
);

INSERT INTO bug1 VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3);

SELECT
  id,
  value,
         (LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value))     lag,
  NULLIF((LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION by id ORDER BY value)), 0) lag2
FROM bug1
ORDER BY id, value;
```

Indeed, running it on PostgreSQL 9 produces the expected output:

```
id  v  lag  lag2
1   1       
1   2   1   1
1   3   2   2
2   1       
2   2   1   1
2   3   2   2
```

But, running it on Redshift produces incorrect results:

```
id  v  lag  lag2
1   1       2
1   2   1   3
1   3   2   
2   1       2
2   2   1   3
2   3   2
```

Is this expected? I [asked on AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=732660#732660) but no reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is not expected; looks like a bug to me. If it was intended, then using `LEAD()` instead and inverting the `ORDER BY` clause, we'd expect the exact same result as in the original `LAG()` query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  value,
         (LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value desc))     lead,
  NULLIF((LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION by id ORDER BY value desc)), 0) lead2
FROM bug1
ORDER BY id, value;
```

But this is what we get instead:

```
 id | value | lead | lead2
----+-------+------+-------
  1 |     1 |      |
  1 |     2 |    1 |     1
  1 |     3 |    2 |     2
  2 |     1 |      |
  2 |     2 |    1 |     1
  2 |     3 |    2 |     2
```

Comment: Did you verify and run this on Redshift?

Comment: Yes, just ran this on my Redshift cluster. I can reproduce the error you're seeing for `LAG()` as well.